# Regular Expression for message

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in eclipse which recognizes the string

```
X.printStackTrace();
```

where 'X' will be the exception variable. My expression is as follows:

```
([^\*\/\/\s])(.*)\Q.printStackTrace();\E
```

This works correctly except on the 3rd line when there are multiple printStackTrace statements in single line.

```
/* e.printStackTrace();
   e.getMessage();
   e.printStackTrace();e.printStackTrace(); e.printStackTrace();
   e.printStackTrace();*/
/* e.printStackTrace();
   e.getMessage();*/
/*
// e.printStackTrace();
   e.getMessage();
*/
```

Can anyone let me know what should be the regular expression if i have to search only

```
X.printStackTrace();
```

on the 3rd line?

Comment: In your example above, which lines/tokens do you want your regex to match ?

Comment: How do you try and match? Note: the star and slash need no escaping in a character class, you could just write `[^*/\s]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `(.*)` part: you have to lazy match using `(.*?)`.

I would have used the following regex though: `[^.\s]+\Q.printStackTrace();\E`

Comment: I also require ignoring block comments so i added ([^\\*//\s]). Thanks for the part on lazy matching. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at this:

```
((?:\w+.printStackTrace\(\);\s*)+?)
```

Check out matches [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/WccxwQgE9S).

**EDIT** : (my regex output at Rubular)

> /* **e.printStackTrace();**
>
> e.getMessage();
>
> **e.printStackTrace();e.printStackTrace(); e.printStackTrace();**
>
> **e.printStackTrace();***/
>
> /***e.printStackTrace();**
>
> e.getMessage();*/ /*
>
> //**e.printStackTrace();**
>
> e.getMessage();
>   */

**EDIT**

For that we need to adjust the pattern to make `greedy (+)` to `ungreedy (+?)`.

Comment: it dodn't work. It still has a problem with the 3rd statement with multiple printstacktrace statements.

Comment: have you looked at the link ?

Comment: yeah..still that isn't working. i checked the expression at Rubular site.

Comment: Hi! my output at rubular is the highlighted part in the edited answer. Does this match is what you expect ?

Comment: In the second match all three printStackTrace(); are matched at one go. I want the matches to be separate. as in for the second line, there should be 3 separate highlights at Rubular.

Comment: @Adithya, I know this question has been answered but still you can check out the new link and the updated pattern.